# Make Specific rows not editable using Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Apex 18.2. I created an interactive report which has 10 records. I try to add a logic that user can only be able to edit those records which recently created. User cannot do an edit to an old records. Means when user try to edit old records, it show as 'Display only' or not editable. Is there any way I can do that? Your help is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create your own **link** (icon, if you wish), just like another column in report's query.

As you're in SQL now, use any condition you want. Obviously, you have to be able to distinguish "old" from "new" rows. If we suppose that it is some `DATE` datatype column, so whatever is "yesterday" or older is considered to be "old", you'd

```
select case when datum < trunc(sysdate) then null
            else 'Click here'
       end as link,
       empno,
       ename
from emp
```

`LINK` column's type would be "link" (of course) and you'd make it navigate to another page in this application, pass values from *here* to *there*, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really helpful. I did try with that link column and now it is working according to my requirement. Thanks again!!